# Using left_join based on two columns does not work in R

Tags: r, left-join

I am trying to `left_join` a dataframe containing cld letters to the main dataframe. The join should be based on two columns. Each row has just one column with values because they come from different models.

Here the main dataframe:

```
main_df<-structure(list(crop = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), till = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"), GW = c("250", "100", 
"500", "250", "100", "500", "250", "100", "500", "250", "100", 
"500", "250", "100", "500", "250", "100", "500", "250", "100", 
"500", "250", "100", "500", "250", "100", "500"), dm = c(12.492780040282, 
21.2330087520355, 9.08920058839951, 9.6579014126203, 32.3208262815535, 
10.6259628492133, 6.13043260006999, 49.6628012967183, 28.8896483162288, 
14.8279966222885, 11.5590504143496, 23.7186742486867, 22.8598403733191, 
8.59025110732551, 20.8781551231343, 34.6812252760796, 25.056901935212, 
11.9791387922734, 2.98603520945085, 20.768615091017, 5.68987327841495, 
35.6382624005007, 24.1315098558383, 32.3442728999024, 35.5586316123229, 
8.36256345081252, 6.06606303991154)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

while here the cld dataframe:

```
cld_df<-structure(list(till = c("Z", "Y", "X", NA, NA, NA, "Z", "X", 
"Y"), .group = c(" a ", "  b", "  b", " a ", " ab", "  b", " a ", 
" ab", "  b"), crop = c("B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"A"), GW = c(NA, NA, NA, "500", "250", "100", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The cld are inside the column named ".group". Both keeping columns as character and converting them to factor lead to an empty column:

```
main_df%>% mutate(till=as.factor(till),GW=as.factor(GW),crop=as.factor(crop)) %>%  
left_join(cld_df%>%mutate(till=as.factor(till),GW=as.factor(GW),crop=as.factor(crop)))
```

Comment: I think you don't have any match for the three common variables.  When you don't specify column names, it will join by the intersecting column names i.e 'crop', 'till', 'GW' which doesn't have a corresponding row.   Also, should be cautious when converting to `factor` and join because there can be chances of having different levels

Comment: Which variables do you use for merge?

Comment: I would like that it uses "crop" and "till or "GW" based on which one is not empty.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```r
main_df %>%
  left_join(select(cld_df, crop, till, .group), by = c("crop", "till")) %>%
  left_join(select(cld_df, crop, GW, .group), by = c("crop", "GW")) %>%
  mutate(.group = coalesce(.group.x, .group.y)) %>%
  select(-.group.x, -.group.y) %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 27 x 5
#    crop  till  GW       dm .group
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
#  1 B     X     250   12.5  "  b" 
#  2 B     X     100   21.2  "  b" 
#  3 B     X     500    9.09 "  b" 
#  4 B     Y     250    9.66 "  b" 
#  5 B     Y     100   32.3  "  b" 
#  6 B     Y     500   10.6  "  b" 
#  7 B     Z     250    6.13 " a " 
#  8 B     Z     100   49.7  " a " 
#  9 B     Z     500   28.9  " a " 
# 10 A     X     250   14.8  " ab" 
# 11 A     X     100   11.6  " ab" 
# 12 A     X     500   23.7  " ab" 
# 13 A     Y     250   22.9  "  b" 
# 14 A     Y     100    8.59 "  b" 
# 15 A     Y     500   20.9  "  b" 
# 16 A     Z     250   34.7  " a " 
# 17 A     Z     100   25.1  " a " 
# 18 A     Z     500   12.0  " a " 
# 19 C     X     250    2.99 " ab" 
# 20 C     X     100   20.8  "  b" 
# 21 C     X     500    5.69 " a " 
# 22 C     Y     250   35.6  " ab" 
# 23 C     Y     100   24.1  "  b" 
# 24 C     Y     500   32.3  " a " 
# 25 C     Z     250   35.6  " ab" 
# 26 C     Z     100    8.36 "  b" 
# 27 C     Z     500    6.07 " a "
```